# A way to prepend letters to each imported class

Tags: scala, syntax, import

Is there a way to import all classes from a package and rename them all by prepending some text? A construct

```
import packages.{_ => Abc_}
```

compiles but seems not to be doing that thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no way to do such a thing.

"Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition" 13.3, which is 2.9 based, defines the rules.  I don't recall anything in the changes for 2.10 that alters the import mechanism.

Given `import package.{selector}`, selector may be one of:

- `x`, a simple name
- `x => y`, renaming `x` to `y`
- `x -> _`, hiding `x` - excludes from names imported
- `_`, the catch-all - import all names.

That's it.  Your variant looks interesting, but isn't in that list.  It is interesting that `{_ => ...}` compiles for various values of `...`, but it's not clear that the effect is any different than `_` for the few trials I ran.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly what you're after, but if you can put up with an extra `.` character, you could write

```
import com.{packages=>Abc}
val x:Abc.Whatever = new Abc.Whatever(...)
```